# Average performance of binary search algorithm?

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-search

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Average_performance

```
BinarySearch(int A[], int value, int low, int high)
{
    int mid;
    if (high < low)
        return -1;
    mid = (low + high) / 2;
    if (A[mid] > value)
        return BinarySearch(A, value, low, mid-1);
    else if (A[mid] < value)
        return BinarySearch(A, value, mid+1, high);
    else
        return mid;
}
```

If the integer I'm trying to find is always in the array, can anyone help me write a program that can calculate the average performance of binary search algorithm?

edit: I know I can do this by actually running the program and counting the number of calls, but what I'm trying to do here is to do it without calling the function.

edit2: KennyTM: That is a time complexity, I'm trying to calculate the average number of calls. For example, the average number of calls to find a integer in A[2], it would be 1.67 (5/3)

Comment: If you are "passonate" (you might want to check the spelling) you have presumably already written some code to do this - share it with us.

Comment: O is "worst case" not "average case".

Comment: @Passonate: Do you want the formula (http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/A001855) or a program to compute the number?

Comment: @KennyTM I want the program to compute the number.

Comment: There's nothing to average over here, the algorithm is completely deterministic.  Searching for A[2] in an array array of size 100 will always take a fixed (and integral) number of calls.  So your average of 1.67 makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a "program".  You can just count the number of calls to the `BinarySearch` method.

You can do that easily by passing another parameter (by pointer) or using a global variable.  In this case - it's a toy - so I'd probably go quick and dirty with the global.

Comment: @Jurily: hehe, no link to instantrimshot.com? :)